# Accidentally killed terminal window before package update during upgrade

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I accidentally interrupted the upgrade process and I am wondering how I could restore it.

I was upgrading from 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS using the graphical tool popped with /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk as suggested in [the 18.04LTS release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes).

I accidentally closed the terminal window and therefore killed the upgrade process at the moment where I got a message like "The packages will have to get updated and this would require many hours" or something similar (I don't exactly remember the message).

Running lsb_release shows that ubuntu has been upgraded, but obviously there were unfinished steps. Please note that the PC is working as usual.

```
:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease               
Hit:3 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease       
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:5 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  php-curl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Is there a way that I could manually continue the process and update the respective packages? Are there other steps to be completed?

Comment: What do you get after running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: @Kulfy: Please check update. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The output looks fine. It must throw an error if some interruptions were made during upgrade. To upgrade `php-curl` as well, run `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade`.

Comment: Is there a way to verify that the upgrade is full and complete?